# Authorizing access to controller based on user claims

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-identity

I know I can restrict access to a controller (or it's members) by decorating it with the [AuthorizeAttribute()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.authorizeattribute(v=vs.118).aspx).

With the advent of ASP identity and moving toward a more "claims based" world I would like to find the equivalent attribute. Something like:

```
 [ClaimAuthorize(Permission="CanCreateCustomer")]
 public ActionResult CreateCustomer()
 {
     return View();
 }
```

Although I'm sure this would come built in to identity, all my searching has drawn a blank.

If it doesn't exist how do I roll my own?

Comment: I've got published proof of concept for claims authorisation before implementing this in production. You can check out the filter: https://github.com/trailmax/ClaimsAuthorisation/blob/master/ClaimsAuth/Infrastructure/Identity/ClaimsAuthorisationFilter.cs and wonder about the rest of the repo.

Answer (score 1):

You have to Roll your Own. From then you can customize it as you want.

You have to Extend Authorize Attribute.

```
public class ClientAuthorize : AuthorizeAttribute
{
    public new String Roles { get; set; }
    public String RequiredRights { get; set; }

    protected override bool AuthorizeCore(HttpContextBase httpContext)
    {
        return CustomAuthorizeLogicReturnsBool(Roles, RequiredRights);
    }

    protected override void HandleUnauthorizedRequest(System.Web.Mvc.AuthorizationContext filterContext)
    {
        if (!filterContext.HttpContext.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
        {
            //filterContext.Result = new HttpUnauthorizedResult();
            base.HandleUnauthorizedRequest(filterContext);
        }
        else
        {
            filterContext.Result = new System.Web.Mvc.HttpStatusCodeResult((int)System.Net.HttpStatusCode.Forbidden);
        }
    }


}
```

Usage

```
[ClientAuthorize(Roles = "ClientUser", RequiredRights = "SaveAdmin,KillAdmin")]
public class AdminController : Controller
{
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should probably put in a documentation request for this, but to get you started you can implement `IAuthenticationFilter`, register it and then decorate your controllers with something like: `[Authorize(Roles = "CanCreateCustomer")]`

```
public class CustomAuthenticationAttribute : Attribute, System.Web.Http.Filters.IAuthenticationFilter
{
    public bool AllowMultiple
    {
        get
        {
            return true;
        }
    }

    public async Task AuthenticateAsync(HttpAuthenticationContext context, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
            context.Principal = //get principal here, based on your implementation
    }

    public async Task ChallengeAsync(HttpAuthenticationChallengeContext context, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        await Task.FromResult(0);
    }
}
```

register it:

```
public static class WebApiConfig
{
    public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
    {
        // Web API routes
        config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

        config.Filters.Add(new CustomAuthenticationAttribute ());
    }
}
```